# Maintain table size but change actor size libgdx

Tags: libgdx

How to maintain my actor size in a table, but keeping the table size the same?
I tried setting height to the table but no luck.

before changing actor image, the table looks like this:

[image: initial table size]

after changing image of actor, unwanted padding and table resized automatically:

[image: after actor size change]

I hope to have something like this:

[image: wish arrangement]

I get this after trying

```
table.add(egg).height(egg.getprefHeight());
```

[image]

How to maintain the table size? I want the brokenDino to be overlay with other eggs without changing the table size.

My table creation codes goes as this:

```
 for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
     {
         Egg egg = new Egg(textureAtlas.findRegion("egg"),textureAtlas.findRegion("eggDino"), 0.5f);
         egg.addListener(ck);
         eggList.add(egg);
         if(i%4==0)
         {
             table.row();
         }
         table.add(egg).size(egg.getPrefWidth(),egg.getPrefHeight());
         if(i==19)
         { 
             table.pack();
            table.setHeight(755);
            table.setOrigin(Align.bottom);
            table.debug();
         }
     }
```

My changing image codes:

```
  for (Egg egg: eggList) {
        if(!egg.isBroken()){
            egg.breakOut();
            table.getCell(egg).size(egg.getPrefWidth(),egg.getPrefHeight());
            table.setHeight(755);
            break;
        }
```

egg is an extend class of Image, and breakOut function is just change other drawable and resize the image itself:

```
 setDrawable(eggDinoDrawable);
    setSize(eggDino.getWidth(),eggDino.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

`eggList.add(egg);`

to

`eggList.add(egg).height(egg.getPrefHeight);`

to fix the cell's height.

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I would like to have my dinoEgg overlap the red box and other egg. (Please look at my question again for new uploaded photo). May i know is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Please have a look at newly uploaded photo.

Comment: Ok I always used the trick with labels that don't scale. Check if you can change the scaling behaviour of the Image actor. If that does not work, don't use the Table but position the image actors yourself. That might be the better solution in this case.